# Kotlin || How to adjust Gridlayout width and height parameters programatically for all screen sizes?

Tags: android, kotlin, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I have a gridlayout with fixed height and weight paramaters. When screensize change automatically ıts getting bigger or smaller. Iv tried all methods but not succeed. How to fix?

My code ;

```
  private fun loadBoard() {
    for (i in boardCells.indices) {
        for (j in boardCells.indices) {
            boardCells[i][j] = ImageView(this)
            boardCells[i][j]?.layoutParams = GridLayout.LayoutParams().apply {
                rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(i)
                columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(j)
                width=340
                height=400
                bottomMargin = 5
                topMargin = 5
                leftMargin = 5
                rightMargin = 5
            }
            boardCells[i][j]?.setBackgroundColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(
                    this,
                    R.color.white
                )
            )
            boardCells[i][j]?.setOnClickListener(CellClickListener(i, j))
           binding.layoutBoard.addView(boardCells[i][j])
```

Comment: Who Can help me ?

Comment: I would specify the size in dp. E.g. width="340dp". The dp means the size of the component will be seen by the user at same size regardless the resolution/size of the physical screen itself.

Comment: Its not possible to allign with string. just required Int type.